# Electron desktopCapture not grabbing audio from single application

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I am looking to build a voice chat application (with screenshare capability), but when using the Electron Desktop Capture plugin, the 'chromeMediaSource' parameter in audio is not taking any effect (Tested on Windows 10).

For some reason, it is capturing the desktop audio in full, meaning that users can hear themselves when watching the screenshare.

Is there any way to only capture one application's sound using this plugin?

Below is the code I am using, which captures desktop audio/video.

```
desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen', 'window', 'audio'] }).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    //console.log(source);
    if (source.id === screenID) {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: screenID,
            }
          },
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: screenID,
              minWidth: 1280,
              maxWidth: 1280,
              minHeight: 720,
              maxHeight: 720,
              maxFrameRate: 60
            }
          }
        })
        handleStream(stream)
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: do you find any soluttion?

Comment: I wish! To this day I still need a solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

```
desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen', 'window', 'audio'] })    
audio: {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
    },
},
```

After a bit of time I found out that this code will work. Be careful to mute your HTML Video Element (You could get a Howl).

Comment: Please, add some explanation.

Comment: I second syscall's comment. Please explain how you isolated one application's audio